# Which interpreted language can work on on microchip PIC32?

Tags: embedded, embed, pic, microchip

I'm looking for an interpreted language that work on microchip PIC32.

Currently, I found that **LUA** and **PAWN** are working but before choosing I would like to know if some other languages are known to work in PIC32.

Comment: Can you define "interpreted language"? The FORTH token interpreter can be implemented with less effort on nearly every CPU.

Comment: I'm looking for a language where i can upload some text file (the program) and the pic32 will be able to run it without the need to compile it, change the firware. I know i can port some interpreted language on pic but i'm looking for some language that are already working without the need to port it.

Comment: @acemtp I have personally 'ported' Lua to the PIC32.  The reason I say 'ported' is because the code is highly standards-compliant and compiled with little modification beyond removing the file system references.  It should be noted that currently the new libc version in C32 seems to break Lua in an unpredictable way (not Lua's fault), so I would use the legacy libc option in the project.  I am very happy with the results.  Feel free to message me if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

There are these two **BASIC** interpreters available:

- [MiniBasic for PIC32](http://www.kiwacan.co.nz/pic32/minibasic/)
- [PIC32-Basic](http://www.pic32.byvac.com/) (proprietary [license](http://www.pic32.byvac.com/downloads/firmware/Licence.txt))

You might also want to investigate how much effort it would take to port an existing **Forth** implementation (e.g. [pForth](http://www.softsynth.com/pforth/) or [LSE64](http://noqsi.com/software.html)) to PIC32.

Answer (score 0):

Parallax has sold their version of BASIC for their own PIC modules for years,

http://www.parallax.com/tabid/295/Default.aspx

although that was PIC16 and PIC18 I believe.

StickOS runs on several PICs, including PIC32.

http://www.cpustick.com/index.htm

> StickOS™ BASIC is an entirely MCU-resident interactive programming environment, which includes an easy-to-use editor, transparent line-by-line compiler, interactive debugger, performance profiler, and flash filesystem, all running entirely within the MCU and controlled thru an interactive command-line user interface.
>
> The StickOS BASIC programming environment includes the following features...

The UBW32 may have the capability to run firmware commands (text based) which are programmed in.  UBW is a very good project for controlling I/O and peripherals... although more like a macro language than an interpreted language.

http://www.schmalzhaus.com/UBW32/

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider the EzSBC1 controller.  Programmed in BASIC with 32-bit variables, 64-bit floating point with trigonometric functions and lots of instructions for direct control of I2C peripherals, SPI chips and hobby servos.  It even has a one line instruction to read data from the HDT11 and DHT22 humidity and temperature sensors.  The code can be password protected.  It has a great 'Getting Started' and 'Programmers Manual'.

More details here http://ezsbc.com/index.php/featured-products-list-home-page/ezsbc1.html

Dan